# Please justify the output in Regex Java program

Tags: java, regex, certificate

I have came across one Java program in Regex .

Below is the program code :

```
import java.util.regex.*;

public class Regex_demo01 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean b=true;
        Pattern p=Pattern.compile("\\d*");
        Matcher m=p.matcher("ab34ef");

        while(b=m.find())
        {
            System.out.println(b);
            System.out.println(">"+m.start()+"\t"+m.group()+"<");
        }


    }

}
```

Output :

```
true
>0  <
true
>1  <
true
>2  34<
true
>4  <
true
>5  <
true
>6  <
```

Doubt : As we all know that The find() method returns true if it gets a match and remembers the start position of the match. If find() returns true, you can call the start() method to get the starting position of the match, and you can call the group() method to get the string that represents the actual bit of source data that was matched. 
My question is how come ">6 <" is present is the output when the string indexing is till index 5 ?

Comment: you are looking for any kind of numbers, let it be `0-n` so every possible `char` of any length fits that regex

Comment: That is last index+1. It is returning that because you've used `\\d*` which allows empty matches as well. You should use `\\d+`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> My question is how come `>6 <` is present is the output when the string indexing is till index `5` ?

That behavior is due to your regex i.e. `\\d*` which matches `0` or more digits.

As you can see it is showing start position `0` as well when there is no digit at the start.

Similarly `6` is **`last index +1`** because there is an empty match past the last character as well.

You should use `\\d+` as your regex.

Comment: Ok  anubhava ! I understood that it matches zero or more characters here and therefore ">6 <" is also included in the output . So considering this concept it should go beyond index '6' i.e 7 , 8 , 9 etc ? If not then why ? Please revert !

Comment: No, it won't go beyond `lastIndex+1` because there is only one empty match past last character in input.

Answer (score 3):

Anser is simple. `x*` matche any count of `x` even `0`.

Replace `*` to `+` which matche to 1 or more element that is left to it.

Comment: In the last iteration of the while loop , how come m.find() returns true even though we have already checked the last index of the string i.e 5 ? I mean how is it looking beyond the last character in the string , it should provide false and terminate .

Comment: `0` is before first character. `6` it is after last.

Answer (score 1):

The star quantifier (`*`) is defined as "zero or more times". That said, your pattern matches zero digits most of the time.

What you actually want is probably the plus quantifier (`+`), which means "one or more times".

Source: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

---

> Why is there a match at index 6?

RegEx doesn't work on a char-basis, but rather inbetween single chars. When matching an empty string, it will look before and after every character. Duplicate findings are omitted, of course, so an empty string after the first char and before the second char will yield one match instead of two. By default the algorithm is greedy, which means it will match as many characters as possible.

**Consider this example:**

Input string is `1`

RegEx is `\\d*`

In this case the RegEx engine starts before the first character and tries to match **zero, one or more digits**. Since it's greedy, it doesn't stop after the empty string it finds at the beginning. It finds a '1' with no digits following. This is the first match. Then it continues the search after the match. It finds an empty string and matches it too, since that equals zero digits.

For RegEx the string '1' looks rather like this:

```
"" + "1" + ""
```

The first two units (empty string and the "1") match the pattern, the third, empty string does, too.

In-depth article about this: http://www.regular-expressions.info/zerolength.html

Comment: In the last iteration of the while loop , how come m.find() returns true even though we have already checked the last index of the string i.e 5 ? I mean how is it looking beyond the last character in the string , it should provide false and terminate .

Comment: Ok Hubert! I understood that it matches zero or more characters here and therefore ">6 <" is also included in the output . So considering this concept it should go beyond index '6' i.e 7 , 8 , 9 etc ? If not then why ? Please revert !

Comment: That is a perfect explanation ! Thanks Hubert for this valuable knowledge .